# How to seed a table with a foreign key using faker.js

Tags: javascript, knex.js, faker

I am trying to seed a table that contains a foreign key using faker.js with knex. The two tables in question are "accounts" and "users". user table contains the accountid field as a foreign key. Now, I can seed the "accounts" table with no problem with this:

```
const faker = require('faker');

function fakeAccount() {
  var account = {
    accountid: faker.random.number(),
    createdat: faker.date.recent(),
    updatedat: faker.date.recent()
  }
   return account;        
}

exports.seed = function(knex) {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('accounts').del()
    .then(function () {
      for (let i = 1; i< 10; i++) {
          fakeAccounts.push(fakeAccount());
      }

      // Inserts seed entries
      return knex('accounts').insert(fakeAccounts);
    });
};
```

When I try to seed "users". I do a request to get all rows from account to iterate and create four users per account id, this is the code. It is no the prettiest code but it should work. The problem is that my promise is returning pending. The function to get all records from the "account" is working perfectly fine:

```
const faker = require('faker');
const db = require('../../accounts/accountdb.js');

async function returnsQueryBuilder() {
  return await db.find();
}


function userbatchfunc() {
  var userbatch = [];
  var fakerarray = [];
  var userarray = [];
  var queryArray = returnsQueryBuilder();
  console.log(queryArray)

  for (let i = 1; i < queryArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
    userbatch = {
        accountid : queryArray[j]['accountid'],
        image : faker.image.avatar(),
        firstName : faker.name.firstName(),
        lastName : faker.name.lastName(),
        email : faker.internet.email(),
        passwordhash : faker.random.number(),
        password: "password1234",
        telephone : faker.phone.phoneNumber(),
        telephone_ext : "",
        registrationDate : faker.date.recent(),
        inactive : "true",
        allowogin : "true" 
      }
      fakerarray = fakerarray.push(userbatch);
    }
    userarray = userarray.push(fakerarray);  
  }  
  return userarray;
}



exports.seed = function(knex) {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('users').del()
    .then(function () { 
       return knex('users').insert(userbatchfunc());
    });
};
```

I get for my account seeds

> Promise { pending }

. In case you want to see the find() function:

```
const db = require('../database/db_config.js');

module.exports = {
    find
}

function find() {
    return db('accounts');
}
```

Can anyone tell me why my promise is not getting resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `var queryArray = await returnsQueryBuilder();` to get the result of the resolved promise.